# Osirix doesn't see my plugin

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins, menu

I'm a beginner in osiris plugin development and in Xcode, and I have to rebuild an old plugin with a lot of  functions deprecated.

**My problem is : After successful compilation and installation of the plugin, the plugin is shown inside the plugin manager but not inside the plugin menu.**

I saw [this tutorial](http://osirixpluginbasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/osirix-doesnt-see-plugin/), but it doesn't help.

So I used the plugin generator to have a clean new project and had my old files and frameworks into it. Compilation and installation successful, but the plugin is still not inside the plugin menu.

I also used the plugin generator to create a Helloworld plugin and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem...

So osiris doesn't see the plugin because I built it in 64-bit mode.

So I changed the architecture of the plugin to 32-bit and it just worked fine.

The reason was my osirix version is 32-bit...

If anyone has a similar problem, don't forget to check the architecture in

*Project -> Build Settings -> Architecture*